# iOS Amazon Cognito S3 metadata filenames

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

How do I get the metadata from my S3 bucket which contains the friendly filename of the file for display purposes.

For example in my table view I have a list of files in the following format:

private/eu-west-1:2dcdgv-des3-3res-fsgr-123456xxxxx/Demo Directory/bxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx

Now this part (the key) "bxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx" should be something like myFile.jpg for example.

Comment: Are you uploading the files? If so, you can attach private metadata (such as a display name) when you upload. But as far as I can tell there is no way to request that metadata for multiple files at once, you have to request it one-at-a-time. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: I am trying to download. Yes you are correct I have to download it one-at-a-time. Question is where can I find a working example of objective c code that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I solved it as follows:

```
-(NSString *)getFileMetaData:(NSString *)fKey
{
__block NSString *fName = @"";

AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
AWSS3HeadObjectRequest *request = [AWSS3HeadObjectRequest new];
request.bucket = @"myS3BucketName";
request.key = fKey;

[[[s3 headObject:request] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSS3HeadObjectOutput *> * _Nonnull task)
{
    if(task.result.metadata != nil)
    {
        //Do something with it...
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle no data
    }
    return nil;
}] waitUntilFinished];

return fName;
}
```